# Error while using Realm Object as a singleton. Is it a good idea?

Tags: ios, iphone, grand-central-dispatch, realm

I'm currently trying to use [Realm](http://realm.io) in my app and I thought of using a subclass of `RLMObject` as a singleton to store the app state.

My first thought is if it's a very bad idea.

My `AppState` class has 2 main methods:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static dispatch_once_t once;
    static id sharedInstance = nil;

    RLMResults *result = [[self class] allObjects];

    if (result.count == 0) {
        dispatch_once(&once, ^{
            RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
            sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
            [realm beginWriteTransaction];
            [realm addObject:sharedInstance];
            [realm commitWriteTransaction];
        });
    }
    else {
        sharedInstance = [[[self class] allObjects] lastObject];
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (void)update {
    RLMRealm *realm = self.realm;

    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    [realm addOrUpdateObject:[[self class] sharedInstance]];
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];
}
```

I have properties for storing several params about the app state.

In one of my view controllers I get the following error:

> 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call
>   beginWriteTransaction on an `RLMRealm` instance first.'

The code snippet where the error occurs is as below:

```
AppState *defaultState = [AppState sharedInstance];
defaultState.appStateX = newAppStateValue; // This is where the app crashes.
[defaultState update];
```

I changed self.realm to `[RLMRealm defaultRealm]` in my `-(void)update` method. No dice!

I feel there is something fundamentally wrong with my understanding of Singletons and/or `RLMObject`s.
Any help is appreciated.

---

**Update**

Based on [Sakamoto's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/629118/kazuki-sakamoto) answer I modified my `-(void)update` method to accept a `block` as an argument.
There is lot of room for error with this approach but I can go ahead and continue with my current implementation without making any drastic changes.

```
- (void)update:(void(^)(void))block {
    RLMRealm *realm = self.realm;

    [realm beginWriteTransaction];
    block();
    [realm commitWriteTransaction];
}
```

I update all the properties within the block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Realm document http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.89.1/

> Realm objects can be instantiated and used standalone just like regular objects.
>
> ...
>
> After you have added the object to the Realm you can continue using it, and all changes you make to it will be persisted (and **must be made within a write transaction**).

The object, that was returned from `[AppState sharedInstance]` method, was already added to the Realm. Thus, changing the properties of the object requires a write transaction as the following.

```
AppState *defaultState = [AppState sharedInstance];
[defaultState.realm beginWriteTransaction];
defaultState.appStateX = newAppStateValue;
[defaultState.realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

Comment: This answer is correct, though a better approach would be to not use a Singleton at all. Not only does it encourage a number of dangerous design patterns, but it will bypass several of Realm's internal design decisions.

Comment: Why don't you post your better approach without Singleton? The basic idea of `AppState` is the exactly same as persistent `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]` singleton pattern.

Comment: Wow! I have read that line in docs but it never registered in my head. I had my own assumption of how these objects work and was trying to use them in that way. As you rightly said I'm trying to use AppState as a replacement for NSUserDefaults. I may have to reconsider that idea. Thanks!